# How to open my flutter app by clicking a url

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter app, and now I need to be able to open my app whenever a URL with a certain pattern is clicked.

In other words, I'd like to have that option from a clicked URL saying "Which app do you want to use to open this link"

and from the shown apps to open this link I want mine to be in there

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Also, I need to say I have done this from Android Studio - Java, but never in flutter/dart, I am a newbie around flutter

Comment: Do you just mean a web app using Flutter? Or Android, iOS, Windows app too?

Comment: @RoslanAmir just android

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea how you open an Android app using a URL. AFAIK, you install an Android app on an Android device.

Comment: Haven't you pressed a url in your phone and it says "Open with" and you have a list of apps? let's say Opera/Chrome/Telegram, and as it is a telegram invitation link you press telegram to open it?

Comment: It is called deep linking as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, this link is going to give you everything you need for deep linking in flutter:

https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

Documentation/Installation